# connect-flash uninstalled by IntelliJ and now cannot install again

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

Im new to node and ive got a peculiar issue.
I was trying to get log in working with passportjs and i had this error where `req.flash()` wasn't working even though i was using it yesterday for the registration it was saying something like `req.flash()` isn't recognized in node models directory or something similar.

After trying multiple ways to get it working i recalled that IntelliJ had asked me to run a npm install command when i opened i. So i clicked the the event log and allowed IntelliJ to do run it, IntelliJ  restarted and I click run and get an Error.

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'connect-flash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\My\Desktop\NodeApp\Test\app.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

So i go to node_modules and connect_flash and the folder  is there but has a  symbol on it.

In IntelliJ below

[image]

In the file explorer below

[image]

When I try to click it in the file explorer i get the following windows error

> C:\Users\My\Desktop\NodeApp\Test\node_modules\connect-flash is not
>   accessible The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system

So i deleted it and attempted to reinstall `npm install connect-flash` which returns errors

> ```
> npm ERR! code ETARGET
> npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for connect-flash@8
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\My\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-30T21_17_28_983Z-debug.log
> ```

And the log file produce  is as follows

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js', 1 verbose cli
>   'install', 1 verbose cli   'connect-flash' ] 2 info using npm@5.6.0 3
>   info using node@v8.11.3 4 verbose npm-session 36d3535b3518b319 5 silly
>   install loadCurrentTree 6 silly install readLocalPackageData 7 http
>   fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-flash 22ms (from
>   cache) 8 silly registry:manifest no matching version for
>   connect-flash@8 in the cache. Forcing revalidation 9 http fetch GET
>   304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-flash 83ms (from cache) 10
>   silly fetchPackageMetaData error for connect-flash@8 No matching
>   version found for connect-flash@8 11 verbose type range 12 verbose
>   stack connect-flash: No matching version found for connect-flash@8 12
>   verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:65:11)
>   12 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:52:18)
>   12 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>   12 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>   12 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>   12 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>   12 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
>   12 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
>   12 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
>   12 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>   12 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20) 12 verbose
>   stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5) 12 verbose stack     at
>   processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5) 13 verbose
>   cwd C:\Users\My\Desktop\NodeApp\Test 14 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>   15 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "connect-flash" 16 verbose node v8.11.3 17 verbose npm  v5.6.0 18
>   error code ETARGET 19 error notarget No matching version found for
>   connect-flash@8 20 error notarget In most cases you or one of your
>   dependencies are requesting 20 error notarget a package version that
>   doesn't exist. 21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Ive never had an issue like this before and  would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own, fro some  reason IntelliJ decided that a the  version number in  pacckage.json didn't need to be there anymore. After i included 0.1.1 for the version i could run an install command  for it